# Eclipse shortcuts do not work

Tags: shortcut-keys, eclipse, c++

I have installed Eclipse Neon with C++ features on Ubuntu 16.04.

My problem is that some more unusual shortcuts do not work such as "copy lines" (ctrl+alt+down), or "move lines up" (alt+up), or autocomplete (ctrl+space) for example. The others more usual like "ctrl+c" or "ctrl+f" or "ctrl+z" do work.

I have tried to restart eclipse, and even the computer. I have restored the defaults key bindings but they do not work anymore. I think they worked just few times at the beginning after installing eclipse.

I don't want to uninstall and then reinstall eclipse because it is not a good solution if I have to do that every time, it will be just bothering at will. While searching for solutions on Google, it seems it is a quite recurrent issue for eclipse, but there is never real answers for them.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug has been reported relating to this issue [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488708).

Reading through some of the comments, it sounds like it may be related to GTK3. One of the comments suggests running eclipse with GTK2 using the following:

> SWT_GTK3=0 ./eclipse

This doesn't fix the issue but may give you a workaround until the bug has been fixed.